# Text area not showing up

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am trying to add a simple empty field to my program, in
which a user can put in his name. Trying this, no text area is visible at all.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel.setSize(800, 600);
JTextArea enterName1 = new JTextArea(50, 50);
enterName1.setRows(20);
enterName1.setColumns(1);
panel.add(enterName1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
enterName1.setVisible(true);
panel.setVisible(true);
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* - Using a `null` layout? Not adding `panel` to a displayable container? Not providing a providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem

Comment: You'll probably also find [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) useful

Comment: `JTextArea enterName1 = new JTextArea(50, 50); enterName1.setRows(20); enterName1.setColumns(1);` is better (shorter) written as `JTextArea enterName1 = new JTextArea(20, 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add your panel to a jframe and make sure it's visible!

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    MyView view = new MyView();

}
```

**View**

```
public class MyView extends JFrame {

    public MyView() {
       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setSize(800, 600);
        JTextArea enterName1 = new JTextArea(50, 50);
        enterName1.setRows(20);
        enterName1.setColumns(1);
        panel.add(enterName1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        enterName1.setVisible(true);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        this.add(panel);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(800, 600);
    }
}
```

**Output** (N.b. I wrote "Hello world!!")

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the panel to a frame or dialog:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.add(panel);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```